# Similar function in JavaScript to convert string/number

Tags: javascript, jquery, type-conversion

I have a function in PHP that gets a number inserted into a text input and converts it to a float, with comma separator for decimals.

After that, the number is registered in the database.

Now, I need to make something with JavaScript (or jQuery), that does the same kind of convertion.

```
$num = $_POST['precoItem'];//get the input value
$precoAd = tofloat($num);//convert it to float
$precoFinal = number_format($precoAd, 2, ',', '');//remove any 'dots' or 'spaces'
```

The PHP function `toFloat()` is this one:

```
function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos : 
    ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);
    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    } 

    return floatval(
         preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . ',' .
         preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep+1, strlen($num)))
     );
 }
```

For example, the final number will not have dots or spaces, only commas: Ex.: 45354,85 (45.354,85)

My JS knowledge is limited. I tried using things like:

```
var n = +$precoFinal;
var n = Number($precoFinal);
var n = parseFloat($precoFinal);
```

**Why people like to downvote so much... Are you really gonna say that my question didn't had any research? Rly?**

Comment: have you tried writing such a function in JS?

Comment: `parseFloat("1234.45") ` ?!

Comment: strrpos = indexOf, floatval = parseFloat, preg_replace = replace, substr = substr, strlen = length

Comment: 45354,85  is not a valid number in JS. You need to also replace the comma with a dot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var str = '45.354,85';
var num = str.split(/[\s.]+/).join('');
num = parseFloat(num.replace(",","."));
console.log(num);
```

Comment: `str.replace(/[\s.]+/g,'');` is more elegant in my opinion

Comment: `console.log(parseFloat(num.replace(",","."));`

Comment: The problem is that the number registered in the database has comma.
So, in order to compare it the way I need, the input number must maintain the decimal comma.

Comment: So you need to convert one of them to be in the same format.... Since the engine does not support comma for decimal, you can't have it as a number, it has to be a string.

Comment: @epascarello thnx for the tip, probably the best way to go is to convert the other value. Faly, thnx for the answer, I upvoted cuz it makes sense and it's useful. To the people downvoting my question, thnx for downvoting and not explaining why, it shows that you are downvoting just for fun.